# How can I add limits to the inputs of an OSL shader?

Tags: scripting, osl

The input of a shader or function is always initialized with a single value, but it can be changed to any value in the node editor.

[image]

Here, I want to limit the value of num to between 0 and 100, but initializing num as range(0,100) doesn't work.

[image]

I can't achieve this in the node editor either.